# python multiprocessing with different functions

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I can't find an appropriate method for the next task: 
I have an input massive [x1, x2, x3 ... xn] and function that I want to apply to every x from massive f(xi, param) so there are eight possible values of this param, and the result of function doesn't depend from param. So I need to run this function f for all possible values of param at the same time. and it's absolutely not important which function work with which x. it's important to all this eight function f(xi, p1), f(xi, p2)... f(xi, p8) works at the same time and all the x will be processed only once.

Answer (score 1):

Seems pretty straightforward. I don't know what you mean by "all the x will be processed only once", but that doesn't sound possible. The function still has to be called separately for each parameter (Unless some black magician on SO can prove me wrong, which seems likely)

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x, param):
    ...do stuff...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    params = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
    try:
        pool = Pool(8)
        pool.starmap(f, [(x,param) for param in params])
    except SomeError:
        ...do error stuff...
    finally:
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
```

Comment: Why are you wrapping this in a bare try-except?

Comment: Probably should have mentioned in my post to catch whatever errors he thinks are relevant, it's only meant to be bare for my example. Oops. If you don't care about the errors you could just use a try/finally to ensure the pool is closed and dead afterwards.

Comment: This won’t work as-is, because you’re only passing the param to `f`, not the `x` list. You probably want to map `partial(f, x)` or a closure. Either that or map over `((x, param) for param in params)`.